# Typescript how to return never from function in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-never

So basicly i have a function, that's starts OAuth flow (redirecting to google oauth login page for example):

```js
async function signIn() {
  // start Oauth flow
}
```

and for instance i want to use it in useEffect like this:

```js
...
useEffect(() => {
  async function someAsyncFunc() {
    randomFunc1();
    await signIn();
    randomFunc2();
  }

  someAsyncFunc();
}, []);
...
```

in this case `randomFunc2()` will never occur because `signIn()` will redirect to another url

So my question is how i can tell for other developers that there's no point to call other functions after `signIn()`, because they will never be executed. I heard in typescript there is type called `never`, but i'm not sure if this gonna work in my case.

**Edit:** as example `redirect` function in nextjs navigation returns never

Any sugestions?

Comment: I'm not sure this needs a TypeScript solution, a dev reading this should be able to understand what's going on, and if it's particularly unclear, that's when you add a comment explaining the process.

Comment: The dev is only going to encounter the `never` if they try to do something with the result, it doesn't really capture the semantics of what you want. I would just mark the return type `void` and leave a comment as suggested by DBS.

Comment: I don't think there is a technical solution here. You could name the function something like `signInAndRedirect` to better indicate that calling it will navigate away.

Comment: If it must be async then I think you can't do this, because of [ms/TS#34955](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34955). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

### This should work but doesn't due to a typescript bug

```
async function signIn(): Promise<Never> {

}
```

But currently this doesn't create errors as expected [due to this TypeScript bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34955)

### Workaround

There is no real neat solution that works right now, but you can at least prevent the most common mistake (code not running that should be run) by just not returning a promise if it will never complete

```
async function _signIn() {
  // start Oauth flow
}

function signIn(): void {
    _signIn();
}
```

`signIn` now does not return a promise, so it can't be awaited. This way it is impossible to do something after `signIn` completes.

You can still write code in the lines afterwards but they will execute like normal, not wait will the sign in completes.

In your example:

```
// doesn't even need to be async now
async function someAsyncFunc() {
    randomFunc1();
    signIn();
    randomFunc2();
}
```

`randomFunc1` and `randomFunc2` will both run as intended, regardless or where you place `signIn`

Note this only works if `randomFunc1` etc. are *not* async otherwise they may not complete before the pages closes.

Comment: @mousetail, it doesn't work like you think: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIxKg5hASQgAoBKALhgAUAndAW1RAFMAeCZgN2ZoD4YA3gCgYMAPRjsyYDWQwA8sATIAFvAA26AO4iYqulpgdDAURp0axAEQ1mAE1S2ocuMFTr7V0kIC+QoaCQsIgoGFj0biSkgrrAWm5yOPhEZLpQmCDoHgB0mrjWTDCocgAO6CA4AEYeeugwKsDcemAlzCBQNKglcvE0WCo8zAD8XuKSUAjmzBDI6mBGdb0QqBC4vv5AA

Comment: @jcalz I replaced it with an alternative approach that should work until the upstream bug is fixed

Comment: @jcalz You copied my code wrong. It should *not* return `never` now. That code will actually complete. If you change it to `void` it will run all 3 lines as expected

Comment: So the alternative approach just lets developers write code after the `signIn()` merely because it's not `async` anymore? Instead of stopping people from writing useless code it allows the useless code to start running (although if any of *that* code is async then it won't complete). I don't really think that's what OP is asking for, but I'll delete my comments since I think this is now in "does this help" territory and not "does this work as advertised".

Comment: @jcalz I agree it's not an ideal solution. Hopefully the upstream bug gets fixed soon so a more elegant version is possible.